# What is the best way to redirect a user to login screen from 2 or more different controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this in my `application_controller`

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :login_required, :only => 'users/login'
    protect_from_forgery with: :exception

    protected
      
      def login_required
        return true if User.find_by_id(session[:user_id])
        access_denied
        return false
      end
    
      def access_denied
        flash[:error] = 'Oops. You need to login before you can view that page.'
        redirect_to users_login_path
      end
end
```

I want  to use the **login_required** for each controller def method

Is there a better way instead of this?

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_user, :login_required, :only => 'users/login'
  #before_action  only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :new]

  def index
    login_required
    @users = User.all
  end

  def new
    login_required
    @user = User.new
  end
end
```

Is there a better way to include `login_required` for all controllers methods since `before_action` doesn't seem to work?

Comment: To me it looks like on `ActionController` you should have `before_action :login_required, except: 'users/login'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the motivation of your logic, so I'll just focus on how you can solve this particular problem.

You can do something like this:

In your application controller:

```rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    before_action :login_required

    private
      def login_required
        current_params = params["controller"] + "/" + params["action"]
        if current_params == "users/new" or current_params == "users/index"
          return true if User.find(session[:user_id])
          access_denied
          return false
        end
      end
    
      def access_denied
        flash[:error] = 'Oops. You need to login before you can view that page.'
        redirect_to users_login_path
      end
end
```

The `login_required` method will just run only on `users` controller's `index` and `new` action, for the rest, it'll just ignore. Also you can just use `User.find()` and no need to use `User.find_by_id()`

Now, in your `users_controller.rb`, you don't need to mention anything about `login_required`, everything will happen already in `application_controller` before coming here.

```rb
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_user, :only => 'users/login'
  #before_action  only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :new]

  def index
    @users = User.all
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I'm going to suggest that you use [devise](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise) for authentication, it's a lot more secure and should deal with this for you.

As for your problem, you should be able to specify the before_action like this:

`before_action :set_user, :login_required, only: [:new]`

Which you can put in your UserController. However if you want this globally, just put it in the ApplicationController, without the `only:` key.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to require login for all pages except `/users/login`, then you almost have it right except you are specifying `only:` when you should be using `except:`:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :login_required, except: 'users/login'
  ...
end
```

This configuration will be applied to all sub-classes of `ApplicationController` as well.